# Why does my ng-grid edit template not close on blur

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-grid

I have an ng-grid table with an editbale cell which I am using angular ui  datepicker for.

```
{
   width: "80px",
   field: "EstInvDate",
   displayName: "Inv Date",
   enableCellEdit: true,
   editableCellTemplate: '<input class="form-control"  type="text" datepicker-popup="dd MMM yyyy"  ng-model="row.entity.EstInvDate" min="minDate" max="\'2015-06-22\'" ng-required="true" />',
   cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()">{{row.getProperty(col.field) | date:"dd MMM yy"}}</div>'
 },
```

The editable cell works fine but nothing happens on blur and the edit box remains showing on the grid.

Anyone have any ideas why?

Comment: Can you post fiddle or Plunker to allow as to play with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably facing the same issue as this previous SO article: [AngularJS (ng-grid) "editableCellTemplate" remains in edit mode on loss of focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17680363)

Try adding **ng-input="COL_FIELD"** to your editableCellTemplate

Answer (score 0):

I've read other SO posts about same problem using datepicker-popup in editableCellTemplate.  For example: [Date picker is not working in AngularJS (ng-grid) "editableCellTemplate"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23394619/date-picker-is-not-working-in-angularjs-ng-grid-editablecelltemplate).  My guess is it's due to incompatibility between ng-grid and that date picker.  They are both from the angular team, but hey no one's perfect:)  I have not read about any solutions :(