# Custom ng-grid edit cell template never goes out of edit mode

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I've been playing a little with `ng-grid`, and tried to understand how to use the `editCellTemplate` option. 
I tried to make a cell editable in the form of a `select` component, and it works pretty awesomely, but after I finish editing and focus out of the cell, it remains in the state of selection, instead of returning to its default state.
[Here's a Plunker of what I tried to do](http://plnkr.co/edit/GBcCAooXoamNTWdFIYbP?p=preview) (click on `height` cells to edit).

Does anyone have an idea how I can make the editable cell go back to its default mode?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS (ng-grid) "editableCellTemplate" remains in edit mode on loss of focus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17680363/angularjs-ng-grid-editablecelltemplate-remains-in-edit-mode-on-loss-of-focus)

Comment: You are right. The answer there solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

a great solution
ng-grid: Editable cell templates remain in edit mode on loss of focus v2.0.7

```
        [2]:https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/5MZITMG_HLo
        <select ng-class="'colt' + col.index" ng-input="COL_FIELD" ng-model="COL_FIELD" data-placeholder="-- Select One --">
    <option>nl</option>
    <option>fr</option>
    <option>en</option>
</select>
```