# How to edit the cells of ng-grid programatically

Tags: ng-grid

I have a ng-grid with edit button on each row. Now, when I click the edit button I would like to have all the cells of that row in editable mode. The same effect as when we double-click each cell. How can I achieve this. Would be great if you can provide sample code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would also be great if you could provide your code as a starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it based on the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17680363/angularjs-ng-grid-editablecelltemplate-remains-in-edit-mode-on-loss-of-focus).

The idea is to add an `edit` property in each document:

```
$scope.myData = [{
    name: "Moroni",
    age: 50,
    edit: false
}, {
    name: "Tiancum",
    age: 43,
    edit: false
}];
```

And then use the **Edit** button to invert that property.

```
$scope.edit = function (row) {
    row.entity.edit = !row.entity.edit;
};
```

Using cellTemplates, you can change the cell to an input :

```
cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText"><div ng-show="!row.entity.edit">{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</div>' +
            '<div ng-show="row.entity.edit" class="ngCellText"><input type="text" ng-model="row.entity.name"/></div></div>'
```

See the working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/q2kyroys/2/).